# A newbie's question about loading and unloading components

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

JavaScript has a disconnectedCallback() function - https://canjs.com/doc/can-stache-element/lifecycle-methods.disconnectedCallback.html

> A lifecycle hook called after the element is removed from the document.

Does it mean that the disconnectedCallback() function is called everytime we for example close our browser or navigate from one URL to another, so the component disappears from the UI?

Comment: This forum is for Salesforce related questions only. For any generic JS library/ framework, you should post it in a JS stack exchange or relevant forum. 
Lifecycle hooks are callback methods triggered at a specific phase of a component instance’s lifecycle (specifically think about DOM insertion. removal etc.). That being said when you close the browser (or explicitly navigating to another domain URL), none of these will be relevant. If you are on the same domain page and the framework JS is modifying the DOM, these callback functions will execute.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that the disconnectedCallback() function is called everytime we for example close our browser or navigate from one URL to another, so the component disappears from the UI?

No. If you need support for that kind of behavior, use [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload). The `disconnectedCallback` will only be called if the component is removed from the DOM, which can only happen if the page's framework is still running (LWC, Aura, React, etc). When a page is unloaded, such as by closing a browser window, all scripts and network connections are terminated.